# different look for sonata admin login page

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Why some sonata pages have two different login pages (look) for admin?

For example: I installed latest sonata admin, user ... and I have login page
[image]

If I look at the official sonata admin demo (http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/login), then the login page is like

[image]

Do I need some extra package, settings ...?

My composer.json looks like

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.6 as dev-master",

        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.4@dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.4@dev",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1@dev",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the demo site they used different styles, you are able to override all the twig templates, take a look here:

[Creating and Using Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)

[Setting up a custom show template](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/action_show.html#setting-up-a-custom-show-template-very-useful)